# Strange margin-behaviour with Sifr spans in link (screens)

Tags: css, hyperlink, sifr, margin

I'm making a menu and it's supposed to look like **picture nr 1** on **[this link](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/1122/strangemarginbehaviours.gif)**.

However, at this moment, it looks like **picture nr 2**.

There's no logic in this behaviour, since all three elements have the same css-attributes. Moreover, let's change the word "Reiki" to "Psychotherapie" and see what happens... (**picture nr 3**)

For some reason the word "Reiki" ignores certain attributes. This is not a problem when Sifr is turned off. I guess I'll need some extra CSS to solve this (messing with paddings, heights or margins on that specific element doesn't give any result. It just won't budge).

**Unless someone knows a more elegant solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **solved** it by adding

```
.sIFR-active .btns a span{letter-spacing: 0.3em; padding-top: 25px; display: block; float: right;}
```

to **sifr.css**. As I vaguely expected, it was an **letter-spacing issue**. But it wasn't really recognizable in this appearance. On top of the previously described problem it showed alright in Firefox but not in IE. With the code above added to sifr.css all looks fine in both browsers.